# How do I import OpenCV library into python 3.1?

Tags: python, opencv

OpenCV 2.1 was first installed when I had the original python 2.6 and this works fine. However after getting the Python 3.1, it has no module called 'cv' after trying to import OpenCV. How to add these modules?

Answer (score 0):

[According to this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315021/installing-opencv-for-python3), OpenCV doesn't support Python 3 and no one is working on Python 3 support either.

Comment: This is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

As of April 2019, you can install opencv for Python 2.7 and 3.4-3.7. It can be installed via `pip` for PythonV2 and `pip3` for PythonV3:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

- In case of installation problems you may need to upgrade your `pip` version (`pip install --upgrade pip`)
- Despite the package name the module is still imported in Python using:

  ```
  import cv2
  ```

See https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/ for details.

Answer (score -3):

Simply use import statement. First go to

```
$ cd /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opencv
```

Then start `python`:

```
$ python
>>>  import cv.py
```

For any other help, refer http://blog.taesoo.org/?p=210 and http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/introduction.html.

Comment: First of all, you don't need to be in any particular folder to import the cv package. Second of all, the OP was asking for Python 3 instructions, and you are talking about Python 2.6. There is a world of difference there.

Comment: -1: this is just wrong Python coding and doesn't answer the question.